# Find next sibling of the same element type

Tags: jquery

Here is a form:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <label>Phone number *</label>
  <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone">
  <label>Email address *</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  <h3>Event</h3>
  <label>Event type *</label>
  <input type="text" name="type" id="type">
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
</form>
```

I have a variable initialized to first `input` element:

```
var cur_input;
```

I want to loop through the form elements, assigning the next input element to the `cur_input` variable in each iteration.

I have tried:

```
cur_input = cur_input.next(); //failed because there are other elements in between
cur_input = cur_input.next('input'); //failed for some reason.
```

Comment: `cur_input.nextAll('input').first()` https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: /\ this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find next sibling of same element type with

```
var inputs = $('form input');        // Get all input under form
var index = inputs.index(cur_input); // Get current index
var next_input = inputs.eq(index+1); // Get next input
```